# kendo grid "editable false" for update, "editable true" for create

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

This is my schema:

```
id: 'EntryCode',
fields: {
    EntryCode: {editable: true, validation: {required: true}, nullable: true},
    width:     {editable: true, validation: {required: true}, nullable: true},
    length:    {editable: true, validation: {required: true}, nullable: true}
}
```

I want that the **EntryCode** will be editable just at **create** option, while at **update** it won't be editable.

How do I achieve this goal without templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because I'm using **editable: inline** I've to find the cell and replace its content as follow:

```
edit: function (e) {
    if (!e.model.isNew()) {
        e.container.find('td:eq(0)').text(e.model.EntryCode);
    }
}
```

to learn more see this [question](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-web/grid/prevent-edit-only-on-update.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

In the grid's edit event, check `e.model.isNew()`, and do `grid.closeCell()`, e.g.:

```
edit: function (e) {
    var fieldName = e.container.find("input[name]").attr("name");

    if (fieldName === "EntryCode" && !e.model.isNew()) {
        this.closeCell();
    }
}
```

([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/a8S9c/) in which the ProductID field is editable for the third (new) row, but not for the first two rows)